How to detect when git stash push reports "No local changes to save"?
I'm using git stash push -a in a script to save uncommitted changes and then sometime later  run git stash pop in the same script to restore the stashed changes.  I've run into a problem in which git stash push -a occasionally reports "No local changes to save" and no no stash is created.  This causes the subsequent git stash pop to fail with exit code 1.  Is there a way I can detect when git stash push -a reports "No local changes to save" so that I know that no stash is created (short of checking the git stash push -a output) and thus not perform the git stash pop?

Cheeky suggestion: touch $(uuidgen) before stashing :)

You can catch the output of git stash and test if it is equal to No local changes to save. In Bash for example, output=$(git stash push -a);if [[ "$output" = "No local changes to save" ]];then no-git-stash-pop;fi.

Instead of git stash examine the very changes. Like git update-index -q --refresh && git diff-index --quiet HEAD. Or git ls-files --deleted --modified --others --unmerged --killed --exclude-standard --directory --no-empty-directory

Botje's "cheeky suggestion" of creating a temporary file so that git stash push -a has at least one file to stash worked for me.  Just remember to delete the temporary file after running git stash pop.

I would rather suggest checking in those changes as normal, but temporary commits and stop using stash because normal commits are much safer in they do not have dangerous, complicated quirks like stash have.
For your use case, you can save with
git commit -am "AUTOSAVE myscript.sh "$(date +%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)""

and then unsave with
if [[ "$(git log --format=format:%s HEAD^..HEAD)" == "AUTOSAVE myscript.sh"* ]]
then
    git reset HEAD^
fi


I don't see how git reset HEAD^ restores the uncommitted changes; rather, I would think that it deletes them.

Also, I don't think git commit -a commits untracked files (i.e. new files you have not told Git about).
